# Quarkus logging over Log4J 2 - configuration in log4j2.yml ignored

Tags: kotlin, log4j2, quarkus

We are using SLF4J over Log4J 2 with all our applications and will do so also with our Quarkus applications.

I am familiar with https://quarkus.io/guides/logging (so I claim). All application log messages over SLF4J->Log4J end up in the console. However, I don't understand what I need to adjust to have Quarkus respect the logging configuration in `src/main/resources/log4j2.yml`. We don't want to configure logging through `application.properties`.

The dependencies to `org.jboss.logmanager:log4j2-jboss-logmanager` and `org.jboss.logmanager:slf4j-jboss-logmanager` are in place.

Comment: Quarkus always logs through JBoss LogManager. The dependencies you can add (`log4j2-jboss-logmanager` etc.) are just bridges that let you use the respective logging facade, while everything still goes to JBoss LogManager behind the scenes. Hence, logging configuration always comes from `application.properties`. (As an exception to the rule, an extension was recently published that allows using Logback: https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-logging-logback/dev/index.html No such extension exists for Log4j 2 as far as I'm aware.)

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could turn this into an answer and accept it.

Comment: Oh, let me copy that into an answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus always logs through JBoss LogManager. The dependencies you can add (`log4j2-jboss-logmanager` etc.) are just bridges that let you use the respective logging facade, while everything still goes to JBoss LogManager behind the scenes. Hence, logging configuration always comes from `application.properties`.

(As an exception to the rule, an extension was recently published that allows using Logback: https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-logging-logback/dev/index.html. No such extension exists for Log4j 2 as far as I'm aware.)